# Change Launch Screen/Splash Screen color and image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The app itself works completely fine. My question is that on the launching of the app itself, the screen is the Unity default blue for a quick second or so before changing to the black of my first scene.

How do I change this color to be black on startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change this by going to **File** --> *Build Settings* --> *Player Settings* --> *Splash Image* --> *Background* --> *Background Color*.

From there you can change the background color. You can also change the image, animation type and overlay opacity from there.

Note that there are things you may not be able to change there unless you have Pro license.

[image]

**EDIT**:

---

<sup>Updated to be more detailed of where to change stuff</sup>

First change the **Splash Image**:

[image]

There are more options for iOS platform but this settings can still be found in the menu I mentioned above.

If iOS, select iOS as your platform and you can change your **Background Color** from there:

[image]

You should then change the **Lunch Screen** type from there. Set it to **None** if you want it to be gone.

[image]

If the color does not still change, you can create a Texture with a color of your choice and add it to the **Mobile Splash Screen** slot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer, but I already have the splash screen disabled. This does not solve my problem.

Comment: That's not what I said in the original question. I figured it out anyway. What was happening is when I launched the app with it disabled, it shows the default unity blue for a second before going to the black of my first scene. I replaced the legacy mobile launch screen with a 1x1 black pixel and that fixed it. I have pro. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm still unable to change the color of the "pre-splash" screen on Android. I have everything set to black color + black texture and tested with Splash Screen Enabled/Disabled. iOS does not exhibit this issue. I'm running Unity 2017.4.18f1 - Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP was looking for the Background Color of the Launch Screens as indicated in these screenshots.

This is taken from an iOS build setting panel. We've observed odd behavior with no textures at all (even though that is what we want), so we use single-pixel, solid-color images as well as a background color to match.

These fields are not made available in the PC/Android build windows, so not 100% sure what the equivalent would be - beyond using flat-colored images. Either way, it is these elements that are used prior to loading your scenes.

[image]

Comment: Yes. You can also just edit the launch/splash screens in the XCode project it generates. Without any texture there it generates a dark blue color for the splash screen for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about the camera background color. You can set it up in your main camera to black. You can find the camera documentation [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html)

Comment: Please read the question carefully before attempting to answer. Also this question already has a correct answer, don't answer again unless you have something important to add. This ain't yahoo answers.

Comment: Neither do splash screens explain why OP is seeing "Unity default blue" nor have other answers been accepted yet. When reading "Unity default blue" I was thinking of scene background color immediately, too. Also the fact that it appears only "a quick second" does not sound like the Unity splash screen to me. Maybe OP is having a startup scene with default blue background and loading another scene shortly after launch.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert No part of OP's question is confusing or hard to read. It says "Unity default blue for a quick second or so before changing to the black of my first scene". When you lunch a Unity program, the camera background or skybox will **not** show quickly then switch to the main scene. Try this yourself. That's 
 the behavior of the *Splash Screen*. It show's the background color with image, if provided then moves to the first/main scene. Also, the splash screen default color is dark blue. As for why the answer is not accepted, some people don't accept answer for days.