# How to get rid of a red screen showing between the mandatory Unity Logo splash (for Personal) and the display of my initial scene?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I am wrapping up fixing some defects in my Unity game.

Sporadically, when I run my game on iPhone 5s I see a full screen of red in between the Unity Logo Splash Screen (mandatory for Unity Personal Subscription), and the initial display of my first scene. This lasts for anywhere between a flash and about half a second. I have never seen this sort of behavior on Android or other iOS devices (besides the iPhone 5s, which is my main test device for iOS).

1) Has anyone seen similar behavior? If not,

2) Any ideas for possible causes and/or ways to fix this behavior?

I am seeing this on a release build built in Unity 5.6.0f3. My initial theory was that the initial scene had too many resources to load which was causing the camera to not render for a few moments after the unity logo finished transitioning out, but I already split my initial scene into an initial loading/pseudo-splash screen scene, and a subsequent scene which contains the majority of the objects in the scene.

Comment: It it doesn't happen on any other device then it's likely a bug. Try what's in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586506/3785314) post. Change the background color, add custom background images. If that doesn't work then file for bug report.

Comment: @Programmer I have already changed the background color as per the details in the linked answer, so this will not solve my issues. Thanks for the suggestion, I will submit a bug report